# Android application force closing on device

Tags: java, android, sqlite

On the Emulator the app runs fine. On the device the moment im trying to copy my database over the application's database and execute a query the app force closes. Any idea why this could be happening? Do i have to request any kind of permissions or something in manifest for it to run?

**Database.Java**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.BHC.www/databases/";

//Name of the Database to be created.
private static String DB_NAME = "BHCLibrary3.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;



 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */


public Database(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    //First we check if the database already exists, Method declared later
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(); 

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exists
    }else{

        //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are going to be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(); //Method declared later

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
          }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */


private boolean checkDataBase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}



/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transferring byte stream.
 * */


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}


//Opening the Database
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


}

//Finally overriding a few methods as required

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //First we check if the database already exists, Method declared later
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(); 

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exists
    }else{

        //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are going to be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(); //Method declared later

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
          }
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

And **Results.java** (The activity i run my query)

```
public class SearchResults extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);


    Database myDbHelper = new Database(null);
    myDbHelper = new Database(this);

  }



 // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);


    SQLiteDatabase myDb = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

 //Executing our query against the server using rawQuery and getting the cursor
    String select="SELECT DISTINCT b._ISBN as _id, b.BookTitle, b.Edition, b.Year, b.Pages, b.Rating, c.Category, p.Publisher, w.LastName" +
            "   FROM" +
            "   Books b" +
            "   JOIN Categories_Books cb ON cb._Books_ISBN = _id" +
            "   JOIN Categories c ON c._CategoryID = cb._Categories_CategoryID" +
            "   JOIN Publishers p ON p._PublisherID = b.PublisherID" +
            "   JOIN Writers_Books wb ON wb._Books_ISBN = _id" +
            "   JOIN Writers w ON w._WriterID = wb._Writers_WriterID" +
            "   WHERE b.BookTitle LIKE '%" + query +"%'" +
            "   OR c.Category LIKE '%" + query +"%'" +
            "   OR p.Publisher LIKE '%" + query +"%'" +
            "   OR w.LastName LIKE '%" + query +"%'" +
            "   OR _id LIKE '%" + query +"%'" +
            "   GROUP BY b.BookTitle";


    Cursor c = myDb.rawQuery(select, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);



 // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { "Books.BookTitle", "Publishers.Publisher" }; 
 // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ISBN_entry, R.id.Title_entry };

 //Getting results into our listview
    try
    {
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listlayout, c, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The error im getting is : java.lang.runtimeexception: Unable to start activity Componentinfo(gr.BHC.www/gr.BHC.www.SearchResults} and then various exceptions saying table books etc dont exist.

EDIT2: I saw the exception im getting usually related with content providers but i still cant figure out why i'd get that.

Comment: Could you post Logcat to look for errors?

Comment: Can you post the logcat?  Particularly where it indicates the exception.

Comment: Also, what's device model and Android version?

Comment: Posting log in a second. Emulator is 2.2 device is 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. I made some changes on your codes and now it is working. Here are the codes:

#### SearchResults.java

```
public class SearchResults extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);

        DbManager myDbHelper = new DbManager(null);
        myDbHelper = new DbManager(this);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        
        myDbHelper.createNewDatabase();

        
        try {
            myDbHelper.open();
            Log.d("Search Results", "database opened");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        // Executing our query against the server using rawQuery and getting the
        // cursor
        String select = "SELECT DISTINCT b._ISBN as _id, b.BookTitle, b.Edition, b.Year, b.Pages, b.Rating, c.Category, p.Publisher, w.LastName"
                + "   FROM"
                + "   Books b"
                + "   JOIN Categories_Books cb ON cb._Books_ISBN = _id"
                + "   JOIN Categories c ON c._CategoryID = cb._Categories_CategoryID"
                + "   JOIN Publishers p ON p._PublisherID = b.PublisherID"
                + "   JOIN Writers_Books wb ON wb._Books_ISBN = _id"
                + "   JOIN Writers w ON w._WriterID = wb._Writers_WriterID"
                + "   WHERE b.BookTitle LIKE '%"
                + query
                + "%'"
                + "   OR c.Category LIKE '%"
                + query
                + "%'"
                + "   OR p.Publisher LIKE '%"
                + query
                + "%'"
                + "   OR w.LastName LIKE '%"
                + query
                + "%'"
                + "   OR _id LIKE '%"
                + query
                + "%'"
                + "   GROUP BY b.BookTitle";

        Cursor c = myDbHelper.rawQ(select);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // the desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] { "Books.BookTitle",
                "Publishers.Publisher" };
        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ISBN_entry, R.id.Title_entry };

        // Getting results into our listview
        try {
            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.listlayout, c, columns, to);
            this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

And your new database helper, DbManager:

#### DbManager.java

```
public class DbManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "BHCLibrary3.sqlite";
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.BHC.www/databases/";
    private static final Integer DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "DbManager";
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DbManager dbManager;

    public DbManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE 'notes' (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public DbManager open() {
        dbManager = new DbManager(context);
        db = dbManager.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void createNewDatabase() {
        InputStream assetsDB = null;
        try {
            assetsDB = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            OutputStream dbOut = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = assetsDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            dbOut.flush();
            dbOut.close();
            assetsDB.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "New database created...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create new database...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor rawQ(String select) {
        return db.rawQuery(select, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should have nothing to do with layout. As said pretty much my problem is: On the emulator i can copy the database succesfully (and thus query it later) and on the device it doesnt get copied and later on crashes the app when i try to query an empty DB

Comment: sorry about that, i deleted the other post.

Comment: Just got home and i kinda have to sleep so no time to check it tonight, ill tell you how it went tommorow. Thanks for the time you spent on this either way tho, was very kind.

Comment: Not at all. I'm waiting for the result.

Comment: It did actually work, not sure what i did wrong tho, any chance you could elaborate on what changed (working app is fine but learning why it wasn't working to avoid in the future is better)

Comment: Firstly you had a problem to copy and open your database. I solved this issue with my recently used DbHelper code. With that code, you can copy your database from your assets folder with Streaming. Then you need to create your database with createNewDatabase() and open your database with open() function where you need to use. Secondly, you used your query in your activity. It is a database code. You have to create your query function in your DbHelper class and you just need to call it with its name, and parameters if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the size of your database exceeds one MB. In that case you need to store it in the assets folder as .jpg and then copy it over. This is because Android places a restriction on the size of the text assets.

Comment: It doesn't exceed 1mb. Also for some reason all of a sudden the app stopped running on the emulator aswell (Crashed on searchresults activity and doesnt copy the database over).

Comment: It worked again on the emulator (I didnt really change anything). On the device it just doesnt want to copy the database for some reason that i cant understand..